# Enforce uniqueness with multiple columns possibly null

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

If I have a table where I want to enforce uniqueness based on multiple columns that can be null during INSERT (using postgres), would I need to create multiple unique index like below?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table_b_id INT REFERENCES table_b(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    column_a INT,
    column_b INT,
    column_c INT,
    created_time BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "table_a_key" UNIQUE ("table_b_id", "column_a", "column_b", "column_c")
);
```

`column_a`, `column_b` and `column_c` can all be null. I want only the unique combination of these columns per record for the table.

**Valid Inserts**

```
table_b_id | column_a | column_b | column_c

 1   |   1   |   2   |  3
 1   |   1   |  null |  null
 1   |  null |   2   |  3
 1   |  null |   2   |  null
```

But, if I try to insert `1 | null | 2 | null` again, it would conflict and not insert.

think adding just the `CONSTRAINT "table_a_key" UNIQUE...` only enforce uniqueness if all the columns don't have any null value.

Do I need to create all these index in order to enforce uniqueness? Is there a better way?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_all_null_index ON table_a (table_b_id)
WHERE column_a IS NULL AND column_b IS NULL AND column_c IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_col_a_index ON table_a (table_b_id, column_a)
WHERE column_a IS NOT NULL AND column_b IS NULL AND column_c IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_col_b_index ON table_a (table_b_id, column_b)
WHERE column_b IS NOT NULL AND column_a IS NULL AND column_c IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_col_c_index ON table_a (table_b_id, column_c)
WHERE column_c IS NOT NULL AND column_a IS NULL AND column_b IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_col_a_b_index ON table_a (table_b_id, column_a, column_b)
WHERE column_a IS NOT NULL AND column_b IS NOT NULL AND column_c IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_col_a_c_index ON table_a (table_b_id, column_a, column_c)
WHERE column_a IS NOT NULL AND column_c IS NOT NULL AND column_b IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_col_b_c_index ON table_a (table_b_id, column_b, column_c)
WHERE column_b IS NOT NULL AND column_c IS NOT NULL AND column_a IS NULL;
```

Comment: I find your question unclear.  What exact constraint are you trying to enforce?  What is allowed and not allowed?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - sorry about that. hopefully it is made more clear now. Will test out your suggested approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow multiple `NULL` columns, then that is what a regular unique index or constraint will do:

```
unique (a, b, c)
```

If you don't want `NULL` values to be duplicated, then the simplest method is to default them to a common value, such as `-1`:

```
unique (coalesce(a, -1), coalesce(b, -1), coalesce(c, -1))
```

That might not work in all cases, but it works in many cases because `-1` (or some other value) is not otherwise used.